# How to create a crystal report with Firebird's Database

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to build a desktop application. I need to create a report but I don't know how to do? I am using to use FireBird for my Database. I am using windows 8.1.

Of course I am not forget to googling, but I do not know what is wrong with my steps.

The following are the steps that I have tried to do :

1. download ODBC Driver from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-ODBC-driver/2.0-Release/Firebird_ODBC_2.0.0.151_x64.exe) and install it.
2. download Firebird-2.5.5.26952-0_x64_embed.zip and extract it to path `C:\Firebird-2.5.5.26952-0_x64_embed`
3. Try to Add ODBC Data Source Administrator like this image

[image]

I try to `test connection` but I get an error `Open Database C:\Users\User\Documents\FDB\TEST.GDB failed`

Whats wrong with my steps?

I am new in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field Database have to be in following format: 
:
for example:
127.0.0.1:c:\Databases\data.gdb